# Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit, code execution order

Tags: assembly, x86

```
    jmp    0x2a                     # 3 bytes
    popl   %esi                     # 1 byte
    movl   %esi,0x8(%esi)           # 3 bytes
    movb   $0x0,0x7(%esi)           # 4 bytes
    movl   $0x0,0xc(%esi)           # 7 bytes
    movl   $0xb,%eax                # 5 bytes
    movl   %esi,%ebx                # 2 bytes
    leal   0x8(%esi),%ecx           # 3 bytes
    leal   0xc(%esi),%edx           # 3 bytes
    int    $0x80                    # 2 bytes
    movl   $0x1, %eax               # 5 bytes
    movl   $0x0, %ebx               # 5 bytes
    int    $0x80                    # 2 bytes
    call   -0x2f                    # 5 bytes
    .string \"/bin/sh\"             # 8 bytes
```

so jump to call then "the strings address will be pushed onto the stack as 
the return address" . Is it this address saved in esi why pop esi ?

Comment: what's the point of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the common way to write [position-independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (code that can be successfully executed, regardless of what address it is located at).

The `call` instruction does two things:

1. Pushes the return address (the address of the instruction immediately following the call) onto the stack
2. Jumps to the address specified.

So after the call, the address of the string "/bin/sh" is on the stack. The next instruction, `pop esi`, takes that address off the stack, and puts it in the `esi` register, so it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when the `call` is executed, it pushes a return address (the address after the call opcode) onto the stack so that when `ret` is encountered (in normal operation), execution continues where it left off. This is the standard x86 calling convention.

In your code, the return address pushed is the location of "/bin/sh". `pop %esi` puts that value into the esi register, which is then as a pointer and passed to syscall `0xb` which is `execve` on a linux system, executing the command named in your string.

There are lots of good resources on [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller_clean-up), of which I expect linux x86 would be of particular interest to you.